# empty when sending mail via HTML

Tags: php, html, email

Some help with the following would be greatly appreciated! I've been searching the web and stackoverflow for hours. There is this problem with my php mail function.

```
<form method="POST" action="contact.php" onsubmit="validateForm()" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<p>Name*</p> <input type="text" name="name" required>
<p>Mail*</p> <input type="email" name="mails" required>
<p>Phone*</p> <input type="tel" name="phones" required>
<p>Subject*</p> <input type="text" name="subjects" required>
<p>Message*</p> <textarea name="messages" required></textarea>
<input type="submit"> 
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

And here is my **contact.php**

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['mails'];
$field_phones = $_POST['phones'];
$field_subject = $_POST['subjects'];
$field_message = $_POST['messages'];

$mail_to = 'example@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_subject;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone : '.$field_phones."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) {?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
            window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to ');
            window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
                </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

When I am trying to `echo`, it is showing but unable to send email via `mail()`

Comment: Sorry, this is unclear: now _is_ $:POST empty as the title suggests or not, as your last statement suggests?

Comment: And what does the function `validateForm()` do? We cannot _guess_ that, so please post its js code.

Comment: Is the email empty, or are you unable to send the email (you mention both)? Do other PHP scripts on the same server send `mail()` properly (maybe it's a `php.ini` issue if not)? Are there any error messages in your server log?

Comment: if mail is not sending it may be problem with your smtp settings

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using php to validate the form. You might also want to use `strip_tags()` and `trim()` for each field but you could try the following.
If you get the error message your posts are empty else something else is wrong

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <ul>
        <li>Name*</li> 
        <li><input type="text" name="name" required></li>

        <li>Mail*</li> 
        <li><input type="email" name="mails" required></li>

        <li>Phone*</li> 
        <li><input type="tel" name="phones" required></li>

        <li>Subject*</li> 
        <li><input type="text" name="subjects" required></li>

        <li>Message*</li> 
        <li><textarea name="messages" required></textarea></li>

        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
        <li><input type="reset" value="Clear"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

contact.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mails']);
    $phones = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phones']);
    $subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subjects']);
    $message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['messages']);

    if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phones) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message)) {
        $mail_to = 'example@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_subject;

        $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
        $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
        $body_message .= 'Phone : '.$field_phones."\n";
        $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

        $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

        $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

        if ($mail_status) {?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
                    window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
            </script>
        <?php
        }
        else { ?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to ');
                    window.location = 'http://www.example.com';
                        </script>
        <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo 'There are empty fields';
    }
}
?>
```

And instead of using javascript to give a pop-up you might want to do something like this:

```
if ($mail_status) {
            header('Location: somefile.php?success');
            exit();
        }else { 
            echo 'Something went wrong';
        }
```

And in that file you can get that success with:

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])) {
    echo '<p>Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.</p>';
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry it's show " There are empty fields " and i'm really have no idea now...

Comment: @user3692339 Well since it returns that error something is posted. To check what is posted do a `var_dump($_POST);` an check what that returns. Another thing you could try is to upload these files to a host (no localhost) sometimes that will give you another error than a localhost would give you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'll find the answer, but maybe I'll stumble upon some things as I go ....
*Remember*, you need and SMTP server that your web-server can speak to. The mail() function
does not work in a sandbox (at home, on your computer) unless you set one up! Also, in php.ini
search for smtp. You can set the domain name or IP of your SMTP server. **But, again, your web-server
must be authorized to send mail to that SMTP server.**

**Note** Eventually, you *will* want to do server side input validation. Also, be *wary* of e-mail injection.

```
//1. Use lowercase post in your <form> tag. You might try removing the onsubmit="validateFrom()" attribute
//of your <form> tag so that you can get a basic submission and e-mail to work.

<form method="post" action="contact.php" onsubmit="validateForm()" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

//2. Use the <label> tag for your control labels.
//3. Self-close the <input> tags

<p>Name*</p> <input type="text" name="name" required />
<p>Mail*</p> <input type="email" name="mails" required />
<p>Phone*</p> <input type="tel" name="phones" required />
<p>Subject*</p> <input type="text" name="subjects" required />
<p>Message*</p> <textarea name="messages" required></textarea>

//4. You should be doing this kind of validation before attempting to copy the values from $_POST
//Better look up empty() in the PHP Manual to make sure that you really want to exclude all that
//empty() returns `false` for.  isset() is probably more appropriate in this situation.
```

[PHP Manual: empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

[PHP Manual: isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if(!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phones) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message)) {
```